# asp.net Button needs to be fired twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, init

I am generating dynamic html controls. The controls are being generated on Init, after the user  has caused a postback by pressing a button. However, he needs to press it twice so that the controls are generated. How can I fix this? Code:

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["id"] != null)
            {
                string id= Session["id"].ToString();
                GenerateDynamicControls(id);

            }
        }
    }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["id"] = null;
    }

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string id = TextBox1.Text;
        Session["id"] = id;
    }
```

Comment: You're only creating the controls if it's a postback explicitly.  Stop telling it to wait until a postback and it will stop waiting for a postback..  What's the confusion?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone I need to create controls after the postback of the button, but it needs **two** postbacks in order to work.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in OnInit and see why the code isn't called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use session for these purposes. Plus your code might fail after subsequent postbacks.

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object state)
{
    base.LoadViewState(state);
    var id = this.ViewState["DynamicControlGeneration"] as string;
    if (id != null)
        GenerateDynamicControls(id);
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = TextBox1.Text;
    this.ViewState["DynamicControlGeneration"] = id;
    GenerateDynamicControls(id);
}
```

Comment: @Knagis This seems to work fine, but can I add the condition `if ((this.ViewState["DynamicControlGeneration"] == null) || (this.ViewState["DynamicControlGeneration"].ToString() != id))` before generating controls to avoid repetition?

Comment: wouldn't a better solution be to disable the button?

Comment: He can write on the TextBox another Id and generate other controls.

Comment: Implemented in my much complicated situation and it works very well. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Session["id"]` is set to null on page load. When the page is posted back after button click, the `OnInit` method is called first and it get the value of `Session["id"]` as `null`. After that the button click event is executed and `Session["id"]` is set. So when you click the button second time the `OnInit` has the value other than `null`  for `Session["id"]` and your code is executed on the second click.

Comment: `OnInit` is called before `PageLoad` therefore it gets the Session variable before it gets null.

Comment: Yes, but on first click of button the `Session["id"]` is not set before `OnInit` because `Button1_Click` is not called before `OnInit`.

Comment: Right.Then, how can I fix it?

Comment: You can not use `OnInit` if you are setting `Session["id"]` with button click back end event. You can set it in the method `OnInit` itself if your logic permits.

Answer (score 1):

Call GenerateDynamicControls(id); when button is clicked. That way you will have your controls on first click. And when page reloads they will be recreated in OnInit.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = TextBox1.Text;
    Session["id"] = id;
    GenerateDynamicControls(id);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I generate controls as strings and then I append them to a div, for instance:  `div1.InnerHtml += html;`. This way they will be appended twice?

Comment: Why don't you want to add them as a child controls? Anyway, you can have a flag in that checks whenever controls are already generated, so as not to generate them for the second time.

Comment: It's a very complicated situation but the main reason is that I don't want them to run on Server because I am manipulating them later with ajax requests, etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
     if (Page.IsPostBack)
     {
         string id = Request.Form[TextBox1.ClientID].ToString();
         GenerateDynamicControls(id);
     }
}
```