# collections in a UserControl losing contents on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, dynamic-usercontrols

I populate a collection in a `UserControl` which then creates dynamic `LinkButton` controls from the collection. When one is clicked, on postback, the collection is empty. Is this behavior by design or is there something I can do to keep the collections populated on postback without re-populating them in code? Do I need to re-query in the forms postback?

Comment: All variables are disposed at the end of a page's lifecycle. That's by design, it's in the nature of the [stateless HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).

Comment: Yet, variables defined on the ASP.NET pages are intact on postback. What mechanism is responsible for that? Why would usercontrols be treated differently?

Comment: @Metaphot: there's no difference between a page and a `UserControl`. Maybe you have a static field which will not be destroyed. However i strongly recommend against using a static field in  a multi threading environment like ASP.NET.

Comment: Controls that are declared static will be recreated automatically on postbacks, dynamically created controls must be recreated manually on postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every variable defined in a class inheriting `Web.UI.Page` will be destroyed at the end of the Page-Lifecycle(incl. controls and fields), hence it will be `null` at  postback if you don't reinitialize it.

One way to persist it across postbacks is to store it in a [Session-variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx).

You will find a complete list of all options on how to persist variables across postbacks here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx

- Application
- Cookies
- Form Post / Hidden Form Field
- QueryString
- Session
- New State Containers in ASP.NET
- Cache
- Context
- ViewState
- Web.config and Machine.config Files
  Conclusion

It's the nature of [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#HTTP_session_state) that it is **stateless**.

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist the information in `ViewState` and recreate the controls when the ViewState is loaded after postback. For example, you could store number of buttons created and then recreate them.

See a similar solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15497035/1711598